# Determine Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr

I was given a shapefile at work with the information that it is in Lambert Azimuth Equal Area (LAEA) projection (EPSG 9820). After some research on the web, I found out that EPSG 9820 is a generic EPSG for all LAEA projections [1].
The *.prj like this:

```
 PROJCS["LAR_LambertAzimuthalEqualArea",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-75.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",-10.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Is there a way how I can figure out the EPSG code based on the *.prj file with open source tools?

[1] http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2008-January/015519.html

Comment: I am pretty sure this doesn't have an EPSG WKID. It doesn't have an Esri WKID. Esri (we) have started inserting an AUTHORITY tag at the end of the well-known text: AUTHORITY["ESRI",102100] for instance. If it's not there, you would probably need the projection engine library to do a look-up or have a current set of wkt to compare against. www.spatialreference.org will output various styles but I don't know how you could mine the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may not be an EPSG code for a specific LAEA, unless some agency has used it (such as a national geological organization, or a petroleum company), and the EPSG (or other authority such as ESRI or OGC), have assigned it a code, *and* someone has had the need to put it into the database for their application.

The clue is in the `central_meridian` parameter, which in your case is -75, and the `Latitude_Of_Origin` parameter (which point to a Peru-centred map). A LAEA projection must specify these lines, but they can be anywhere on the globe, so there would have to be infinite number of `authority` codes to cover them all!

It must be remembered that EPSG codes aren't "magic", they are only a convenience in looking up the projection parameters in a database (and as a shorthand when talking to colleagues); and it is these parameters that are used to transform the data from one CS/projection to another.

What you could do if you use this projection often, is to assign your own codes in whichever database you use. Proj.4 (which is the *de facto* library for cartographic projection) allows you to create your own text file databases mapping codes to projection parameters, or even append to an existing one like the file called `epsg` in the Proj.4 directory. An example of this is the "Google" Spherical Mercator projection that was originally assigned to EPSG:900913 which is way off the bottom of the official list. Eventually the EPSG adopted it and gave it the official code EPSG:3857

Comment: +1 Good discussion and analysis which actually answers the question and clears up much of the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

According to [http://prj2epsg.org/search](http://prj2epsg.org/search.html?terms=PROJCS%5b%22LAR_LambertAzimuthalEqualArea%22,GEOGCS%5b%22GCS_WGS_1984%22,DATUM%5b%22D_WGS_1984%22,SPHEROID%5b%22WGS_1984%22,6378137.0,298.257223563%5d%5d,PRIMEM%5b%22Greenwich%22,0.0%5d,UNIT%5b%22Degree%22,0.0174532925199433%5d%5d,PROJECTION%5b%22Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area%22%5d,PARAMETER%5b%22False_Easting%22,0.0%5d,PARAMETER%5b%22False_Northing%22,0.0%5d,PARAMETER%5b%22Central_Meridian%22,-75.0%5d,PARAMETER%5b%22Latitude_Of_Origin%22,-10.0%5d,UNIT%5b%22Meter%22,1.0%5d%5d) there are 4404 EPSG SRIDs for that WKT projection.

Comment: That narrows it down! :-)  (The search looks worthless to me: the projections it returns match the target text in some, but not all, aspects.)

Answer (score 1):

If using [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/), the command *[ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html)* might give the information you need. In a Linux box:

`$ ogrinfo -al /path/to/myshapefile.shp`

If available, you will find the information you are looking for in the first lines of the command output.

GDAL is available for MS Windows via [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/).

Comment: This tool appears just to read what is in the .prj file.

Comment: After some research, I have also the same impression.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using Quantum GIS - www.qgis.org.  It is able to read and write shapefiles, as well as other spatial formats.  When you add a shapefile vector layer, it reads the .prj file and shows what projection it is in, under properties.  I think that it also lists the EPSG code as well.  I think it tries to assign the best matching EPSG code based on parsing the .prj file.

Hope this helps.